# Difference of Granting Permission in GCP Storage and in GCP IAM

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-iam

We can grant permission in a specific GCP storage bucket. It defines what service account (SA) has what roles (permission) to this bucket. Let me call it bucket level permission.

We can also grant permission of storage in GCP project IAM. It can define what SA (whether in the same or different projects) has what roles to all the buckets of the current project. Let me call it IAM level permission.

I have confusion about the difference btw. setting permission from bucket level and IAM level:

In the case that SA and the bucket are in the same project, does the service account's final permission equals to the subset or superset of the bucket level permission and IAM level permission? e.g. if bucket level grants storage.object.admin to the SA and IAM level grants storage.admin to the SA, then is the final permission the SA gets storage.object.admin (subset) or storage.admin? and is the permission for only this bucket or all buckets in the project?

Besides, in the case that SA (projectA) and the buckets (projectB) are in the different projects, is it true that we must add the SA as the principle of the projectB's IAM, otherwise, SA cannot access the bucket? besides, in this case, will the final permission SA get storage.object.admin or storage.admin only this bucket? Or will it get storage.admin permission to all buckets in projectB?

Comment: IAM policies are bound to resources. Policies are additive (inherited), except for deny policies and constraints. The order that policies are applied: ORG, Folder, Project, Resource. In your case, the bucket and its objects are simply another type of resource.

Comment: Hi there. Adding up to what @JohnHanley mentioned.
If you grant permissions to the bucket level, the SA will only have such permissions in that bucket only.
Now if you assign the bucket IAM permission at the project level, the SA will have those permissions in EVERY bucket that is or will get created in that project.

For case B, and depending on your use case, you can do either of them.
Grant the permission at the bucket level or the projectB for the SA that resides in projectA

Comment: Thanks both! still confuse and want to clarify these 2 questions: 1/ if both bucket level permission & project level permission are defined, is it correct that project level perm. will take effect? e.g. when SA & bucket are in the same project, if project level role = storage.objects.get, bucket level role = storage.objects.list, final perm. is storage.objects.get of all buckets of that project? 2/ if SA & bucket are in different projects, must we define project level permission in order for SA to be able to access that bucket? if yes, how to define it so that SA can only access that bucket?

Comment: after readin https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/policies#inheritance, I think the answer for question 1/ above is: SA will get both project level permission and bucket level permission: i.e. SA can access role = storage.objects.get for all buckets and storage.objects.list of that bucket; for question 2/: the link did not mention how access of diff. projects are handled so I am not sure. below link said we should add SA of project A to project level IAM of project B for SA to access bucket at project B. is it true? https://www.cloudquery.io/blog/creating-cross-project-service-accounts-in-gcp

Comment: Did you have time to check my answer? It helped you to solve your issue? If not, I am happy to assist further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes In order to access the buckets of other projects using the Service Account which is created in different projects. You need to provide access to those Service Accounts using IAM in the project where you have storage buckets and to do that we recommend you to follow this document. Make sure you have given [permission](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles#legacy-roles) for only one bucket, not the entire project.

Follow [Attach a service account to a resource in another project](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/attach-service-accounts#cross-project),

Additionally you can also refer the following documents for more information:

1. [IAM hierarchy along with GCS bucket](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/resource-hierarchy-access-control#example_cloud_storage)
2. [IAM hierarchy level](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam#granting_roles_at_the_project_level_bucket_level_or_managed_folder_level)(folder->Project->Bucket)

Comment: @ Sai: Thanks. I read your link (Attach SA to a resource in another project) and 1/ verified my system has iam.disableCrossProjectServiceAccountUsage not enforced. 2/ After that: I added SA of projectA to IAM of projectB (gs bucket is in prokectB). I thought by not disable-cross-project (i.e. do 1/),  and then setup cross-project in 2/, the resource of projectA should be able to access gs bucket of projectB, but it cannot. I will investigate and let you know.

Comment: If you have multiple service accounts, you can create a [Google Group](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/groups-in-cloud-console) and grant the group as a whole the permissions you would like all the service accounts to have, such as "Storage Object Creator" . You can grant them permissions at the organization level, which means that they will have access to the storage buckets of all projects within that organization.

Comment: Check this [stack link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71527204/) for more information and check if you have any [constraints](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/org-policy-constraints#constraints) applied to the bucket which can block the access.

Comment: Sai: days ago I tried to allow SA of projectB to access another bucket of projectA. after I added SA of projectB to permission of the bucket, the SA of projectB can access the bucket now. In fact in IAM part of projectA, I did not need to add entry to allow SA of projectB to access that bucket of projectA. not sure what happened. I will just accept your answer anyway. Thanks